# Installing pygsl module [Python 2.7, anaconda]

Tags: python-2.7, dependencies, pygsl

I'm having some troubles installing pygsl on python 2.7 with anaconda.

It keeps me printing the same error: "check dependencies". The modules name that appeared was the one that I'd try to install and the IP address. I already uninstalled the IP address and tried to install after pygsl and appeared an error again.

I have this code that I need to simulate and change after. I know it's a rookie question and that probably someone already asked the same, however, I already tried many suggestions that I saw and I still keep failing the solution.

Thank you in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: Can you please be a bit specific about, what step did you follow to install it, what system are you using?

Comment: So, I used Anaconda Prompt to install the modules I needed to install. First, I install gsl: `conda install -c conda-forge gsl`. Then, I tried to install pygsl: `conda install -c ilan pygsl`. I think the problem could be the system I'm using, which is the win32.

Comment: I removed anaconda and installed python through pip. Now, I could install pygsl, but the only way I could was through this link: [https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygsl/ ]. The problem is that when I run the script, jupyter notebook print this error: **No module named pygsl.spline**. My system is Windows 10, 64 bits and the python version is 2.7.15